# Django- Foreign key constraint failed related error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am new in Django, I'm making an item-category exercise. each item belongs to a category via a foreign key.I'm not able to understand problem in my code during submission of item detail. I'm getting an error "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed".

I wrote the code for models.py which is working fine in the admin dashboard of Django, but if same thing I'm trying to implement by HTML form page, I'm getting error.

```py
    models.py

class ColorCat(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="other")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ListItems(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='item')
    item_cat = models.ForeignKey(ColorCat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, null=True,blank=True)
```

```
views.py

def index(request):
    list = ListItems.objects.all()
    cat = ColorCat.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'colorlist.html', {'color': cat, 'item':list })


def colorlist(request):
    new_list = ListItems
    new_cate = ColorCat

    if request.method=="POST":

        item = str(request.POST["item"])
        cat = str(request.POST["category"])
        f_key = ColorCat.objects.filter(name="orange").get()
        new_list(name="item").save()
        new_list(item_cat=f_key.id).save()
    item = ListItems.objects.all()
    color = ColorCat.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'colorlist.html', {"item": item, "color": color})


def addcat(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        newcat = str(request.POST["name"])
        ColorCat(name = newcat).save()
        item = ListItems.objects.all()
        color = ColorCat.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'colorlist.html', {"item":item, "color":color})
```

```html
colorlist.html
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content%}
<h2>Welcome in color cards</h2>


    <form action="addcat" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <lable>add new cat<input type="text" name="name"></lable><br>
        <label>submit<input type="submit"></label>

    </form>


    <form action="colorlist" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>new item<input type="text" name="item"></label><br>
        <label>cat<input type="text" name="category"></label><br>
        <label>add item<input type="submit"></label>

    </form>

<!--see saved result-->

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>categories</th>
        </tr>
        {% for cat in color %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{cat.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>category item </th>
        </tr>

        {% for clr in color %}

        {% for itm in item %}

        <tr>
            {% if clr.name == itm.category %}

            <td>{{itm.name}}</td>
            {%endif%}

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Error
IntegrityError at /color/colorlist
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Comment: Note:1. in views.py, at someplace like(f_key =ColorCat.objects.filter(name="orange").get()) I gave value manually "orange". 2. in views.py, colorlist() till line " f_key = ColorCat.objects.filter(name="orange").get()" the code running ok but  " new_list(name="item").save()" onwards throwing error

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone allof your code - there's lots of irrelevant stuff - but I've noticed a couple of errors:

- definition of `ListItems` model, it doesn't make sense to define a default value for field `item_cat`, it'll try to link the instance with a `ColorCat` instance with id `0` which probably doesn't exist

```py
item_cat = models.ForeignKey(ColorCat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

- saving a `new_list` - use `ColorCat` instance instead of its `id`

```py
    new_list(item_cat=f_key).save()
```

Comment: @sanghmitra if this answer helped you, please *accept this answer* to mark your question as resolved